# IE HTML5 audio files hang on windows localhost - works in all other browsers and on web

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, html5-audio, freeze

I have mp3 audio files which work flawlessly in firefox & chrome. In ie 10 and 11 they also work flawlessly on my live website.

However, suddenly on a Windows 7 localhost a sample file will work fine in one instance but the next, the audio control hangs. For example, the following code worked with a file 1.mp3. I copied 1.mp3 (also tried with rename) to some-other-name.mp3 and it would not work - just hangs with the control visible. I cleared website data and temp files but no luck. I renamed the file back to 1.mp3 and now it no longer works. What could be going on? It was working in ie 10 before it auto updated itself to ie 11. I uninstalled the update and am back to ie 10, but this didn't help. Again, on my live site, everything works, even in ie. Driving me crazy.

I've have code to completely take javascript out of the equation. Even with javascript disabled, it still freezes. Something is up with IE but what? Is this codec hell?

```
<table>
    <td><a href="?mp3file=1.mp3". onClick="CreateAudio('1.mp3', 'divid'); return false;">Play</a></td>
    <td><div id="divid"></div></td>
</table>

<?php
    if (isset($_GET['mp3file'])){
        // only here if javascript disabled
?>
        <audio id="audioplayer" preload controls autoplay style="width:225px ;">
                    <source src="<?php echo $_GET['mp3file']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
<?php
}           
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
currentAudioPlayerID="";
function CreateAudio(mp3file, id){
    // remove old player
    if (currentAudioPlayerID!=""){
        var oldaudio = document.getElementById("audio-" + currentAudioPlayerID);
        oldaudio.parentNode.removeChild(oldaudio)       
    };

    // add new player
    currentAudioPlayerID=id;
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');

    var source= document.createElement('source');
    source.type= 'audio/mpeg';
    source.src= mp3file;
    audio.appendChild(source);

    oggfile = mp3file.replace(".mp3",".ogg");
    source= document.createElement('source');
    source.type= 'audio/ogg';
    source.src= oggfile;
    audio.appendChild(source);

    audio.setAttribute("id", "audio-"+id)
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.appendChild(audio);

    audio.load;
    audio.play();
    audio.controls = true;
    audio.autoplay="True"
    audio.style="width:225px;"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, using the phrase 'localhost' actually can mean two very different things.  Are you directly opening a file from your desktop (double-clicking an icon or even typing the address into the titlebar as it is on the local filesystem: C:\Users...\etc) or are you actually running a local server that is trying to produce the output?

Comment: No I am not attempting to open the mp3 from the filesystem (although the file opens just fine this way into any media player). I have a localhost server and the above code is called as a web page from firefox, chrome, and ie.

Comment: Have you tried using different variable names for `source` on each filetype?

Comment: Good idea. I named the second source to source2 but got the same result. I then removed it completely (ogg isn't necessary) but got the same result.

Comment: I've added code to completely take javascript out of the equation. Even with javascript disabled, it still freezes. Could this be a codec problem?

Comment: I have an idea.  Try instead of using `"?mp3file=1.mp3"` as the URL for the link, do this instead:  `"?" + Date.now() + "&mp3file=1.mp3"`.  Been looking around and found a few more things so if that fails to change anything, let's head into a chat so troubleshooting can be smoother

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47068/discussion-between-deryck-and-mseifert)